# Auto Loading of Kernel Module in Android

Tags: android, kernel-module

I am working in porting REALTEK Wi-Fi Driver in Android LOllipop. The driver is configured as  kernel Module and the 8192du.ko file is generated in the output directory under system/lib/modules. As the upper layer implementation is not yet completed, I wanted to check the driver working by installing the module manually using insmod after booting the Android. But unfortunately, when the Android boots up,the driver seems to be installed automatically. And my wifi GUI is hanging. I assumed this  auto-loading of the driver might be happening from init.rc but no entry for this module loading in any of the init.rc files. Even when the USB dongle is not connected to the device,the driver is loading successfully. How can I stop this module from being loaded during boot up?....Any idea?

Comment: I got the reason...it was checkAndStartWifi() which  will be called during boot up and restore the wifi previous state. My device had wifi state as on and it was restored on every boot.